# Centos : mailx not sending emails

Tags: centos, email

I have a centos server which I am trying to configure for mailx.  I have installed mailx using

```
yum install mailx
```

All seems to have installed correctly.  I am now attempting to send a test email using the following...

```
echo 'this is a test'| sendmail -s test_email myemailaddress@hotmail.com
```

All looks correct but no email is ever recieved, on checking the logs at /var/log/maillog i see this...

```
Dec 30 14:46:57 myserver sendmail[9503]: rBUEkuwh009503: from=root, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=2, msgid=<201312301446.rBUEkuwh009503@myserver>, relay=root@localhost
Dec 30 14:46:57 myserver sendmail[9512]: rBUEkuhk009506: to=<root@myserver>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=local, pri=32952, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Dec 30 14:46:57 myserver sendmail[9514]: rBUEkveo009514: <test_email@myserver>... User unknown
Dec 30 14:46:57 myserver sendmail[9503]: rBUEkuwh009503: to=test_email, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=60000, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Dec 30 14:46:57 myserver sendmail[9514]: rBUEkveo009514: from=<root@myserver>, size=227, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201312301446.rBUEkuwh009503@myserver>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Dec 30 14:46:57 myserver sendmail[9503]: rBUEkuwh009503: to=myemailaddress@hotmail.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=60000, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (rBUEkveo009514 Message accepted for delivery)
Dec 30 14:46:57 myserver sendmail[9503]: rBUEkuwh009503: rBUEkuwi009503: DSN: User unknown
Dec 30 14:46:57 myserver sendmail[9514]: rBUEkveq009514: from=<>, size=1709, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201312301446.rBUEkuwi009503@myserver>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Dec 30 14:46:57 myserver sendmail[9503]: rBUEkuwi009503: to=root, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31024, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (rBUEkveq009514 Message accepted for delivery)
Dec 30 14:46:57 myserver sendmail[9517]: rBUEkveq009514: to=<root@myserver>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31868, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Dec 30 14:46:57 myserver sendmail[9516]: rBUEkveo009514: to=<myemailaddress@hotmail.com>, ctladdr=<root@myserver> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120227, relay=mx1.hotmail.com. [65.55.37.104], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Dec 30 14:46:58 myserver sendmail[9516]: rBUEkveo009514: rBUEkweo009516: DSN: User unknown
Dec 30 14:46:58 myserver sendmail[9516]: rBUEkweo009516: to=<root@myserver>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31413, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

I have now tried sending an email to a confirmed email account testemailaccount@hushmail.com, no email arrives and I see this in the logs...

```
Dec 30 16:21:32 myserver sendmail[29502]: rBUGLWxP029502: from=root, size=15, class=0, nrcpts=2, msgid=<201312301621.rBUGLWxP029502@myserver>, relay=root@localhost
Dec 30 16:21:32 myserver sendmail[29503]: rBUGLWGS029503: <test_email@myserver>... User unknown
Dec 30 16:21:32 myserver sendmail[29502]: rBUGLWxP029502: to=test_email, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=60015, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Dec 30 16:21:32 myserver sendmail[29503]: rBUGLWGS029503: from=<root@myserver>, size=242, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201312301621.rBUGLWxP029502@myserver>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Dec 30 16:21:32 myserver sendmail[29502]: rBUGLWxP029502: to=mailtestaccount@hushmail.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=60015, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (rBUGLWGS029503 Message accepted for delivery)
Dec 30 16:21:32 myserver sendmail[29502]: rBUGLWxP029502: rBUGLWxQ029502: DSN: User unknown
Dec 30 16:21:33 myserver sendmail[29503]: rBUGLWGU029503: from=<>, size=1724, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201312301621.rBUGLWxQ029502@myserver>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Dec 30 16:21:33 myserver sendmail[29502]: rBUGLWxQ029502: to=root, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31039, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (rBUGLWGU029503 Message accepted for delivery)
Dec 30 16:21:33 myserver sendmail[29506]: rBUGLWGU029503: to=<root@myserver>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31883, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Dec 30 16:21:34 myserver sendmail[29505]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mx9.hushmail.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Dec 30 16:21:34 myserver sendmail[29505]: rBUGLWGS029503: to=<mailtestaccount@hushmail.com>, ctladdr=<root@myserver> (0/0), delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=esmtp, pri=120242, relay=mx9.hushmail.com. [65.39.178.143], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Dec 30 16:21:34 myserver sendmail[29505]: rBUGLWGS029503: rBUGLYGS029505: DSN: Service unavailable
Dec 30 16:21:34 myserver sendmail[29505]: rBUGLYGS029505: to=<root@myserver>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31428, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

Strangely with this email address I get the following message in terminal

```
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me that you're doing anything wrong.  The line

```
relay=mx1.hotmail.com. [65.55.37.104], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
```

suggests that your local sendmail is correctly trying to connect to hotmail's primary MX, correctly trying to deliver the email, and correctly reporting that hotmail's refusing to accept it on the basis that the user is unknown.

Either hotmail's telling the truth, and you really are trying to send to an invalid address (be careful before dismissing this hypothesis), or it's lying.  If it's lying, the usual reason is that it thinks you're a spammer, and it's decided to refuse to accept email from you in the most efficient way that SMTP allows.  If you conclude this is what's happening, then your question has changed completely into "how do I improve my sending server's reputation", and that is a whole different question with much longer answers.

**Edit**: from the test you sent below, I see local logs that say:

```
Dec 30 16:40:45 lory sendmail[25598]: NOQUEUE: connect from [217.147.85.xx]
Dec 30 16:40:45 lory sendmail[25598]: STARTTLS=server, relay=[217.147.85.xx], version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=NO, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Dec 30 16:40:45 lory sendmail[25598]: rBUGejti025598: ruleset=check_mail, arg1=<root@mysite>, relay=[217.147.85.xx], reject=553 5.1.8 <root@mysite>... Domain of sender address root@misite does not exist
Dec 30 16:40:45 lory sendmail[25598]: rBUGejti025598: from=<root@mysite>, size=496, class=0, nrcpts=0, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v6, relay=[217.147.85.xx]
```

I note that you have configured your sendmail with a non-globally-resolving hostname, and apparently an unqualified one at that, so that when it announces itself to a fellow mailserver, it does so with a hostname that can't be resolved (`mysite`).  That is **certainly** why my mail server refused your test, and it's probably why others are doing so, too; invalid hostnames in HELO are a standard signature of a spammer.  So fix that and you might start to get mail delivered.

Comment: myemailaddress@hotmail.com was just a dummy account I put in for this post, but I get the exact same result trying to send to a known working hotmail account.

Comment: Probably the latter of MadHatter's two hypotheses then.

Comment: have you configured a smtp relay? http://cri.ch/linux/docs/sk0009.html

Comment: Should that be a comment on the OP's question?  **I** certainly haven't configured one.

Comment: I get the exact same message in the server logs when trying to send an email to any address, even known confirmed working ones.

Comment: You said that above, but it's not clear if you mean only to `hotmail.com` addresses.

Comment: Sorry, same message in the logs when trying to send to any domain

Comment: Please edit an example of that into your question.  I'm particularly curious to know if the IP address of the refusing server is the same.

Comment: Original Post updated with a new example

Comment: Could you try sending one to `reaper@teaparty.net`, which is a dead drop on my mail server?  If that gets refused as well, we might have some idea why, server-side.

Comment: Mail sent, seeing the same errors in the log this end

Comment: Could you post the logs from your end, so I can cross-correlate them with my end?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12215/discussion-between-madhatter-and-fightstarr20) (though I can't seem to open the chat session, so that's probably not a good plan.  All I want to know is the **time** you sent that test; was it by any chance 16:40:45GMT, give or take a couple of seconds?)

Comment: It was 16:40:43 according to my logs

Comment: That explains things perfectly!  I am off to try and fix now